# Subclass objects with one array from superclass object

Tags: java, object, inheritance, subclass, superclass

For example: I suppose ant1 has it's own "path" array, and ant2 has different one "path" array. Is it possible to both ant1 and ant2 have one (and the same) "path" array which belongs to "anthill"?

```
        class Anthill{
            protected int MAX_X=15;
            protected int MAX_Y=15;
            protected int[][] path=new int[MAX_X][MAX_Y];
            public void print(){
            for(int i=0;i<MAX_X;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<MAX_Y;j++){
                            if(path[i][j]==0){
                                    System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            else if(path[i][j]==1)
                                    System.out.print("x");
                            else
                                    System.out.print(".");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
            }
            }

            public static void main(String arg[]){
                    Anthill anthill=new Anthill ();
                    Ant ant1=anthill.new Ant();
                    Ant ant2=anthill.new Ant();
            }

            class Ant extends Anthill{
                    int x=0;
                    int y=0;



                    Ant(){
                            Random ranGen=new Random();
                            x=ranGen.nextInt(MAX_X);
                            y=ranGen.nextInt(MAX_Y);
                            super.path[x][y]=1;
                    }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to revisit your object model. Your `Ant` class is an `Anthill`, which doesn't make a lot of sense. In the case that you've described, each instance of `Ant` has its own `path` field. Perhaps if you refactored so that each `Ant` has a reference to a single `Anthill` you would have the behavior you want.

Comment: Yeah, i think you are right. Separate classes, Antihill and Ant. One object of Anthill with path, and few Ant's. Every single ant referse to anthill object and it's path. It would made have sense.